# Prevent document being indexed in DSE search

Tags: solrj, datastax-enterprise

I am using DSE search to build index of some Cassandra table and I want DSE search not to index a document if some boolean field is true.

I can achieve the same result by filtering during query time but as the number of documents containing true could be large, preventing them from being indexed may provide better query performance.

What is the best way to achieve this goal in DSE search/Solr?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to split up the docs you do want to index into a separate table and not index your main table.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. This is a valid solution and I have actually considered it before asking. However, this method brings some extra complexities in my codes when creating and updating the data. I would rather have a solution that only touches Solr so that I can achieve better separation of concern in my codes.